# Get value of input from editable bootstrap?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I using bootstrap-editable of bootstrap3 library. I want to get value of input tag. Ex: I click on `username` and edit into *myname* and how can I get the value **myname**?

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  //toggle `popup` / `inline` mode
  $.fn.editable.defaults.mode = 'inline';

  //make companyname editable
  $('#username').editable();

  //make status editable
  $('#username').editable({
    type: 'text',
    pk: 1,
    url: '/post',
    title: 'Enter user name',
  });
});
```

```html
<a href="#" id="username" data-type="text" data-pk="1" data-url="/post" data-title="Enter username" name="username">superuser</a>
```

Comment: I see on all your questions you do not mark as 'answered/correct'. If an answer helps, then please dont forget to mark the best answer as correct by clicking the tick `:^)`

Answer (score 1):

In official docs it says:

```
$('#username').on('save', function(e, params) {
    alert('Saved value: ' + params.newValue);  
});
```

Answer (score 0):

check the [`update`](http://vitalets.github.io/bootstrap-editable/#events) event:-

```
$('#username').on('update', function(e, editable) {
    alert('new value: ' + editable.value);
});
```